# SVN checkout new branch based on local files of old branch

Tags: svn, merge, branch, svn-checkout

Someone branched our trunk and now I need to checkout the new branch. I already have trunk checked out locally. Since its a huge repo with GBs of files, it will take forever to checkout the new branch.

But since very few files have changed between the trunk and the new branch, how can I just copy my local trunk, call it the branch, then svn up the differences? Thanks!

Bonus: How to do it where I don't even have to copy trunk, just work off the differences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you want [svn switch](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re27.html)

In your working copy (of trunk), just `svn switch <url/to/branch>`